# spawning a new terminal and writing to its stdout

Tags: c, terminal

I have an application that uses a gui to do most of its interface with the user. However I would like to have a separate terminal window that I can write to for some error checking, raw values etc.

I know I can spawn a new terminal with the `system()` command but I have no idea if interaction is possible.

in the best possible scenario I would like to have a function which takes a string(char array I know...), and prints it to the newly spawned console window:

something like:

```
int func(char *msg) {
    static // initiate some static interface with a newly spawned terminal window.

    // check if interface is still valid

    // send data to terminal

    return 0; //succes

}
```

Comment: have a look into ncurses

Comment: I know ncurses, but as far as I know ncurses doesn`t allow me to spawn NEW terminal window, only take control of the current opened window. I have used ncurses in several application prior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open a pipe.
2. Fork.
3. In the child process, close the write end and `exec` to an `xterm` running `cat /dev/fd/<rdfd>`.
4. In the parent process, close the read end and write to the write end.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    (void)argc, (void)argv;

    int fds[2];
    if(pipe(fds) == -1) {
        abort();
    }

    int child_pid = fork();
    if(child_pid == -1) {
        abort();
    }

    if(child_pid == 0) {
        close(fds[1]);
        char f[PATH_MAX + 1];
        sprintf(f, "/dev/fd/%d", fds[0]);
        execlp("xterm", "xterm", "-e", "cat", f, NULL);
        abort();
    }

    close(fds[0]);
    write(fds[1], "Hi there!\n", sizeof("Hi there!\n"));
    sleep(10);
    close(fds[1]);
    sleep(3);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You can use `fdopen` to turn `fds[1]` into a `FILE *` that you can use `fprintf` and such on.

Comment: I like this approach, forking and using the pid is probably far easier than opening another process separately and sending commands through a socket.

Comment: thank you. It works! even though I kind of have a dislike for `fork()`

Answer (score 0):

Well, imagine a scenario where the terminal **is** your main output device (e.g. tty[n]), how would one open a "new" terminal then?

The only reason you can open multiple terminals in a graphical DE is because they are terminal **emulators**. You would need to launch another terminal emulator and write to the standard output of that using something like a socket or maybe shared memory.

Comment: tl;dr : no standard way

Comment: that kind of sucks... `/dev/pts` contains all virtual terminals but is there a way I can Identify or 'name' a newly spawned terminal? `pts` would allow me to spawn a new terminal but linking it to a terminal emulator is not documented

Comment: Just open a socket and send your commands and what-not through that to the other terminal, then all you need is the same port number. If you don't want to do that you could use a shared file or shared memory (the shm approach would be faster) but that is a huge security risk; if that matters from your point of view

Comment: [posix_openpt()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_openpt) followed by [unlockpt()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/unlockpt) then get the name (/dev/pts/x) with [ptsname()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ptsname)