# Is it possible to output on multiple terminal windows within a single program?

Tags: terminal

This question is very close to the following question:

[Is it possible to output on multiple terminal windows within a single C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803327/is-it-possible-to-output-on-multiple-terminal-windows-within-a-single-c-program)

Yeah, I removed the the letter c. The above link shows how to do this on linux.
I was wondering, can this be done on windows and osx as well?
And if so how?

And also, can it work with "third party" terminals, like iTerm on osx or cmder on windows?

The language preferred to achieve this is java, but not required.

Comment: Ok, for Windows see this answer and the comments on it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57241985/2193968

Answer (score 0):

if i correctly understand, you need to create pipe to the terminal window, in order to send data to it. If found a link for you, which may help. [spawning a new terminal and writing to its output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522680/spawning-a-new-terminal-and-writing-to-its-stdout)

Comment: That is also a linux based answer - may work on OSX (since it is linux based) but I can't tell.  It won't work on Windows though.